# Chrome extension that auto press keyboard

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that auto click, it works at Inspect views but seem not work on other page like [Keyboard counter](https://clickcounter.io/keyboard-counter)

Here are my files:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Auto Spacebar Presser",
  "description": "Automatically presses spacebar button every 3 seconds",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]
,
"action": {
    "default_icon": { "16": "icon.png", "32": "icon.png", "48": "icon.png" },
    "default_title": "Auto Space Presser",
    "default_popup": "",
    "on_click": { "action": "toggle" }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
let isActive = false;
let intervalId;

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  isActive = !isActive;
  const icon = isActive ? "icon-active.png" : "icon.png";
  chrome.action.setIcon({path: icon});

  if (isActive) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Key pressed");
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: () => {
          document.body.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 32}));
        }
      });
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
});
```

It should add to the count on [Keyboard counter](https://clickcounter.io/keyboard-counter) but it not, and the console log still running at the Inspect view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the listeners in your console
[image]

When you investigate that site, you will see that they are updating the count on `keyup`, rather than `keydown` like you are using in your extension.

Changing your code to that event it starts registering